# Is there is any solution to show output of node JS in vs code terminal

Tags: node.js, nodes, node-modules, node-fetch, node-request

I am a new learner of nodejs. I am  using VScode for node Js file. The output of the file is shown in the node JS terminal, But for my convenience, I want to do it in the VScode terminal. when I wrote 'node'  in the VScode terminal rather than display me output of the file in the terminal it gave me different options to open node Js file (notepad, opera, VScode, etc.) and did not show results in the terminal.Is this possible to learn the new node JS  version (19.00) from an old version(14.15.4) of the JS node?

I want to see Node JS file output in Vs code terminal . I don't want the VS code terminal  give me the option  with which I want to open the file just show me the
output

Comment: you just type `node` in VS terminal? or `node myscript.js`?

Comment: It's not working. It is giving options again.

Comment: Anybody, please help me to open the index.js file with nodeJS in vscode